# Chained http get calls, Angular 2, typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, http-get, chaining

In an Angular 2 form, I need to retrieve the firstname and lastname from a `http get call`, providing a `user_id`, which is retrieved by a previous `http get call` to another endpoint.

I know there are similar issues with `async http get calls`, but none of these truly helped me.

So, the first call receives `user_id` field, without providing anything to the server:

```
/API/system/session/unusedid
```

It returns this -->

```
{user_name":"rgar003","session_id":"0635400936","is_technical_user":"false","user_id":"403"
```

Having this `user_id (403)`, I can call this other endpoint and retrieve its `userName` and `lastName`:

```
/API/identity/user/403    //403 or whatever the user_id is
```

It returns this -->

```
{"job_title":"dsf","userName":"rgar003","lastname":"Garcia","firstname":"Robert"}
```

So, I need to provide first name + lastname into a disabled form input. Right now I'm just providing the `user_id`.

The template with the disabled field in which the name and lastmane shoud be shown:

```
<div class="col-sm-5">
    <label for="petitioner">Petitioner</label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="data.petitioner" type="text" class="form-control" name="petitioner" disabled>
</div>
```

The `home` component, from which a function is called to load the petitioner `user_id` from backend:

```
constructor(private workflowService: WorkflowService, private parametersService: UrlParametersService, private _ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {

this.formMode = parametersService.formMode;

  // origin:  /API/system/session/unusedId
  this.workflowService.loadPetitioner().subscribe(
    res => {
      this.data.petitioner= res;
    }
  );
```

The `workflow.service` that contains that function:

```
constructor(private http: Http, private parametersService: UrlParametersService, private router: Router, private _configurations: ConfigurationsService) {}

public loadPetitioner(): Observable<string> {
  return this.http.get("/API/system/session/unusedId", {withCredentials: true}).map(value => value.json().user_name);
}
```

I tried different chaining ways, but all failed.
If I call to `/API/identity/user/403`, so providing a `user_id` hardcoded, then it works fine getting firstname + lastname. Like this:

```
getPetitionerFirstNamePlusLastName(): Observable<string>{
return this.http.get("/API/identity/user/403",  {withCredentials: true}).map(value =>(value.json().firstname + " " +  value.json().lastname));
}
```

I seems that there is an async problem here, but I cannot resolve it, even after having checked other similar issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try

```
this.workflowService.loadPetitioner().concatMap( res => {
      let id = res;
      return this.getPetitionerFirstNamePlusLastName(id);
}).subscribe( res => {
      // Do stuff with the user
});
```

And in the getPetitionerFirstNamePlusLastName add **id** as an argument

```
getPetitionerFirstNamePlusLastName(id:number): Observable<string>{
     return this.http.get("/API/identity/user/" + id,  {withCredentials: true}).map(value =>(value.json().firstname + " " +  value.json().lastname));
}
```